# Why is my Query not working? 'Exception Value: Cannot use QuerySet for "Conversation": Use a QuerySet for "Profile" '

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to query `Conversation`, which has a many to many field called `members`. I am doing this so that I can then pass `Conversation` to my `InstantMessage` object because that object has a foreign key called `conversation` that attaches to `Conversation`. I need to check if members are apart of `Conversation` first, and then if so, get, or if not, create, and then pass that into my `InstantMessage` object. But for some reason, I am not able to query it and I don't understand why.

**error**

```
Exception Value:    
Cannot use QuerySet for "Conversation": Use a QuerySet for "Profile".
```

**views.py/message**

```
def message (request, profile_id):

    other_user = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)
    members = Conversation.objects.filter(members= request.user).filter(members= other_user)
    conversation, created = Conversation.objects.get_or_create( members = members)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = MessageForm(request.POST, instance= request.user, sender=request.user, conversation = conversation, message=message, date=date)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect ('dating_app:messages.html')
    else:

        conversation, created = Conversation.objects.get_or_create( members= [request.user, other_user])
        form = MessageForm(instance= request.user, sender=request.user, conversation= conversation, message=message, date=date)

        context = {'form' : form }

        return render(request, 'dating_app:messages.html', context)
```

**models.py/Conversatin and InstantMessage**

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)




class InstantMessage(models.Model):


    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

Comment: A suggestion to improve your chance of getting a good anwer here: **reduce this down to just enough code to reproduce the error**. It's unlikely we need your whole models file. It's a lot to read; we want to know _how_ you produced the error.  Include the exception name too. 

Ideally you'd share a Python interactive session (`manage.py shell`) where you produce the error. 

As a bonus, the work you put into helping other people reproduce the error may well lead you to the solution.

Comment: Ok got it. Is that better?

Comment: I think you replied (thank you!) as I was editing my comment.  Give us steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: It's not about there being an error as I wrote if you read it. It's about steps to go about accomplishing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The same principle applies. At a bare minimum, indicate what line raises the error you reported.

Comment: My bad , you're right. I actually advanced a bit further, but still stuck, so I'm gonna make a new question.